Google Forms prefill link with emailaddress
Google Forms has this nifty functionality of:

having Google to send the user an email upon submit
prefilling (entry.NUMBER=etc)
GET request to /formResponse?submit=Submit to just send off another GForm response

Now, I'm looking to combine all of these in this setup:

I have website with a form
I'd like to send that information to the GForm
AND I'd like the Google Form to send the user the email

The thing is: I just can't seem to be finding a way to also send along the emailAddress & emailReciept=true in a way Google seems to accept that.
So the happy flow would be:

User only fills in my form on the website
Website triggers REST API call to GForm and formdata gets send over
GForm sends user email

I have done several GET & POST requests, also debugging a live recreated form in Chrome Dev but I just can't seem to make it working that my requests (which come back as 200 OK) are being accepted and recorded
Edit: restating question.
So what I'm hoping to find here is someone helping me forward to a way to send data over in one call, preferably a GET call with /formResponse?submit=Submit with the emailAddress & emailReciept=true information included.

I do suggest that you should transfer the data into sheets and make functions that can send mail using apps script.

@LimeHusky How would you trigger that in Google Sheets?

@LimeHusky my problem is exactly that: getting the data there. I could also skip the whole email part, but that's just exactly what I'm trying to accomplish here.

my problem is exactly that: getting the data there I'm sure there are other/better explanations, but have you read Save HTML Form Responses to Google Sheets - it's a step-by-step tutorial on Medium. Covers getting data to Sheets and it uses the onFormSubmit trigger, so you can add sending the email into your own script.

I've tried something like that yesterday at https://mrinalcs.github.io/submit-html-form-to-google-form but also that fails, because of the email collection on the form - and answers not properly fitted are just discarded. I'm really looking forward to a working solution to submit a form via GET/POST with email collection enabled, thank you.

You can use this documentation about the sheet API Google Sheets API.

having Google to send the user an email upon submit "Collect email addresses" is the key and there are 2 options: 1) Verified: the respondent is required to sign in to Google; this doesn't apply in this scenario. 2) Responder input where respondents manually enter their email address. This address has no "entry" number and, to the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to submit the email address So... .AND I'd like the Google Form to send the user the email Would you please explain why you want the Google Form to send the email.

@LimeHusky You can use this documentation about the sheet API May I ask, what's in the Sheets API that will enable OP to solve their problem with "email collection in a Google Form"?

An external website contains an HTML form. The goal is to:

submit form responses from the HTML form to a given Google form
AND
have the Google Form send responders a copy of their response.

This is not possible.
In order for Google Forms to send responders a copy of their response, one must adjust the Settings option Send responders a copy of their response.
This option relies on capture of an email address in one of two ways:

Verified - the respondent is required to sign in to Google.
Responder input - respondents manually enter their email address.

Neither of these methods of collection can apply in the proposed scenario since respondents never interact personally with the Google Form.
Of course, it IS possible to design an HTML Form/Google Form question that requires an email address and to submit the answer to the question but this will not trigger the Google Form to send the respondent a copy of their Form submission.
Workaround
An HTML form can submit responses to a Google Form OR to a Google Sheet. Both Forms and Sheets have an installable onFormSubmit trigger. This can be used to generate an appropriate email to each respondent.
